# Why does mySQL return 0 results on my LIKE query?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_datetime` LIKE '2011-11-11' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I have a record already with the values

```
order_datetime
2011-11-11 02:07:07
2011-11-11 01:07:07
2011-11-11 00:07:07
2011-11-11 11:07:07
```

It just returns 0 results. Clearly I don't want to search the time part as that always changes. I just want to select all records with 2011-11-11 inside them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `order_datetime` is a DATETIME field:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE DATE(`order_datetime`) = '2011-11-11' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I found this the best solution. Mixed it with $todayTotal = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE YEAR(order_datetime) = '".$year."' AND MONTH(order_datetime) = '".$month."' AND DAY(order_datetime) = '".$day."'"); - broke it down even further using strtotime(); thanks

Comment: Why do you think it's better to break down the parts of the date like that? Have you tested it or benchmarked it? I would go for the original solution using the MySQL DATE() function. Let MySQL deal with things it's built to deal with rather than trying to hack around it in PHP.

Comment: I aggree to @liquorvicar - splitting the date up into year, month and day is unnecessary.

Comment: What is the type of `order_datetime`? Have you tried `WHERE order_datetime = '2011-11-11'`?

Answer (score -1):

`Like` should be used with wildcards `%` or `?`. In your example the request should be

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `order_datetime` LIKE '%2011-11-11%' LIMIT 0 , 30
```

`%`  means "any character, any number of times"

`?` means "any character, exactly one time"

Comment: Anybody dare explaining downvoting? :)

Comment: Using a string search in datetime fields is slow and unnecessary. Just use functions that are made for date manipulation.